# Creating Bootstrapper Package when all prerequisistes are not in the same root directory setup.exe

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, windows-installer

I am new to creating Bootstrapper packages. Currently I created Bootstrapper package in which all prerequisistes (VC++, IPP, Windows Installer 3.1, application.mxi) will be inside one single folder and setup.exe will be located outside. For this, I kept product.xml which has product code details for all prerequisites and en folder which has package.xml in the root directory (Bootstrapper\Packages\Dependencies). Actually the problem that I am facing is that, the 'displayname' which is generic for all prerequisites. I want the displayname for list all missed out prerequisites while installing. If I keep all prerquisites in the same root directory of setup.exe  with separate product.xml and en folder for each prerequisite, then it shows the displayname properly. But I need folder structure is like setup.exe should be outside the prerequisites. Is there any possibility not to keep product.xml in the root directory of setup.exe?

```
<Project DefaultTargets="DoPostBuild" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSIName>Test</MSIName>
    <MSIFile>$(MSIName).msi</MSIFile>

    <DeploymentPath>D:\Test</DeploymentPath>
    <TargetPath>$(DeploymentPath)\$(MSIName)</TargetPath>


    <BootstrapperPath>D:\Bootstrapper</BootstrapperPath>
    <BootstrapperPackagesPath>$(BootstrapperPath)\Packages</BootstrapperPackagesPath>   

  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CreateTargetDirectory">
    <Exec Command="rmdir $(MSIName) /s /q" WorkingDirectory="$(DeploymentPath)" />
    <Exec Command="md $(MSIName)" WorkingDirectory="$(DeploymentPath)" />
  </Target>


  <Target Name="CopyMSI" DependsOnTargets="CreateTargetDirectory">
    <copy SourceFiles=".\Test\Release\Test.msi" DestinationFiles="$(TargetPath)\$(MSIFile)" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="MakeLinks" DependsOnTargets="CreateTargetDirectory">
    <Exec Command="md $(TargetPath)\IPP6_0" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(TargetPath)\IPP6_0" Command="mklink /H ipp_runtime_6_0_x86.msi &quot;

$(BootstrapperPackagesPath)\IPP6_0\ipp_runtime_6_0_x86.msi&quot;" />

    <Exec Command="md $(TargetPath)\vcredist_x86_2005" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(TargetPath)\vcredist_x86_2005" Command="mklink /H vcredist_x86.exe &quot;

$(BootstrapperPackagesPath)\vcredist_x86_2005\vcredist_x86.exe&quot;" />
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>

    <BootstrapperFile Include="IPP.Runtime.6.0.x86">
      <ProductName>IPP 6.0</ProductName>
    </BootstrapperFile>
    <BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Visual.C++.8.0.x86">
      <ProductName>VC++ 2005 Runtime</ProductName>
    </BootstrapperFile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="BuildBootstrapper" DependsOnTargets="CopyMSI;MakeLinks">
    <GenerateBootstrapper
      ApplicationFile="$(MSIFile)"
      ApplicationName="Test"
      BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)"
      ComponentsLocation="Absolute"
      ComponentsUrl="($TargetPath)"
      CopyComponents="false"
      Culture="en"
      Path="$(BootstrapperPath)"
      OutputPath="$(DeploymentPath)"/>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="DoPostBuild" DependsOnTargets="BuildBootstrapper" />
</Project>
```

}